# hrtimer going off sooner than what I programmed it

Tags: android, c, timer, callback, kernel

I am trying to set of a hrtimer to generate period function call backs at absolute intervals.

Initializing the timer as

```
hrtimer_init(&p->rt_track.rt_period_timer, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
```

Function assignment is being done as

```
p->rt_track.rt_period_timer.function = new_period_actions;
```

Function prototype is

```
enum hrtimer_restart new_period_actions(struct hrtimer *timer);
```

Setting off timer as

```
hrtimer_start(&p->rt_track.rt_period_timer, ktime_set(t.tv_sec, t.tv_nsec), HRTIMER_MODE_REL);
```

Even though the timespec t is = (10 secs , 0 nsecs) (while I am testing) the timer keeps going of within a few milliseconds causes the kernel to crash by overwhelming the system I guess.

I want to control the timer callback duration by programming the timespec t.

Can someone please tell me what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it using timer forwarding

```
now = hrtimer_cb_get_time(timer);

hrtimer_forward(timer, now,ktime_set(rtt->T.tv_sec,rtt->T.tv_nsec) );
```